# If $A$ has two non zero eigenvalues and is diagonalizable, then $A$ is not identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $p(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1$. Is it true that, if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is identity matrix?

Here is my thought. It's easy to see that two eigenvalues are $-1$ and $-1$. If $A = PDP^{-1}$, then apparently $D = - I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. As a result, $A = -PIP^{-1} = -PP^{-1} = -I$.

What confuses me is the following in the solution:

> It has eigenvalue $−1$, but no zero eigenvalue. Hence the result follows.

I don't get it. How is zero eigenvalue important here?

Comment: @Aweygan Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem either with the solution or problem statement. The identity matrix of dimension $n$ has eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity $n$. Ergo, if a matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 1$, it cannot be the identity matrix. This claim is easy to prove directly: consider what happens if you multiply the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ by $A$.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I know $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = -1$. My point is I don't see how zero eigenvalue comes into play here...

Comment: @Misakov I still don't understand the question -- if any of the eigenvalues are not 1, then clearly the matrix is *not* the identity matrix.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. My confusion was that, I thought solution would be "...but no eigenvalue $1$"...So I was thinking perhaps I missed some facts about linear algebra?

Comment: @Misakov No, I think the question is just wrong. In any case, zero eigenvalues are completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Ummm OK. Unfortunately it's one of the few practice problems I could find for GRE Subject. Thank you.

Comment: @Misakov My best guess is that they meant for the polynomial to be $p(x)=x^2-2x+1$ so that there is a double eigenvalue of $1$ (not $-1$). In this case either the matrix is nondiagonalizable (e.g. $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$) or it is the identity. In the latter case this follows by taking a diagonalization $V \Lambda V^{-1}$, then noticing that $\Lambda=I$ hence $V \Lambda V^{-1}=V V^{-1}=I$.